# How to compare two Lists of objetcs for difference in objects fields?

Tags: java, collections

Collegues, I have two lists of different objects.

`List<SharesEntity> MainSystemSecurities; 
List<SecureEntity> SupportSystemSecurities;`

Objects `SharesEntity` and `SecureEntity` have one same fiels ISIN.
In some case ISINs are the same in object of theese collections, but in some cases there are different ISINs in `SupportSystemSecurities` and `MainSystemSecurities` collection's objects.

I need to understand which objects (better to tell ISINs) from `SupportSystemSecurities` list are absence in `MainSystemSecurities`.

How to do it? What is better way to compare two collection (to compare filedls of the collection's objects)?

Comment: Build a `Map<Isin, SharesEntity> map` from the first list, then use `map.get(isinFromSupportSystemSecurities)` to get the item in the first list corresponding to an item in the second.

Comment: Is Isin a unique field? If Not @AndyTurner

Comment: @ShankarShastri then build a `Map<Isin, List<SharesEntity>>` or a multimap.

Answer (score 2):

Build a `Map<IsinType, SharesEntity>` from the first list:

```
Map<IsinType, SharesEntity> sharesEntityMap =
    MainSystemSecurities.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(SharesEntity::getIsin,
                         Functions.identity()));
```

Then you can iterate the other list, looking up entities from the first list in this map:

```
for (SecureEntity secureEntity : SupportSystemSecurities) {
  SharesEntity correspondingSharesEntity = sharesEntityMap.get(secureEntity.getIsin());
  // ...
}
```

This assumes that there is a single item per ISIN in the first list. If that's not the case, you can build a `Map<IsinType, List<SharesEntity>>` instead, and proceed similarly (or use a `Multimap`).

Answer (score 1):

In the most simple way you can use a loop and if statement to compare each object in both lists and then store the different objects in new lists. Your if statement will be like

```
If (MainSystemSecurities [i].ISIN == SupportSystemSecurities [j].ISIN){
List1.add (MainSystemSecurities [i]);
List2.add (SupportSystemSecurities [j]);
}
```